# MapBox (mapbox-gl-vue) renders the map on only 50% of the width of the container

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying MapBox with Vue 2 and I cannot make the map take the full width of the container. It only renders on 50% of the width of the container.

I have included the files in the head of my index.html as follows:

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>

<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

I want the map in a component (Map.vue, I am using vue-router), so here is the code in Map.vue:

Script:

```
import Mapbox from 'mapbox-gl-vue';

export default {
  components: {
     'mapbox': Mapbox
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<mapbox access-token="pk.eyJ1Ijoic3BlZW5pY3Q....."
    :map-options="{
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
      center: [-96, 37.8],
      zoom: 3
    }"
    :geolocate-control="{
      show: true, 
      position: 'top-left'
    }"
    :scale-control="{
      show: true,
      position: 'top-left'
    }"
    :fullscreen-control="{
      show: true,
      position: 'top-left'
    }">>
  </mapbox>
```

Style:

```
 #map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
 position: absolute;
 margin:0;
 z-index:1;
}
```

I have tried everything I know in the CSS id but it only renders the map in the right half of the width of the container, in the left one only the logo and the controls are displayed while the rest of the area is empty.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To solve the problem, I just had to delete "text-align: center;" from #app in App.vue.

For more details, check the issue I had opened here:
https://github.com/phegman/vue-mapbox-gl/issues/11

Comment: as I wanted to keep the `text-align: center;`, I added a `<div>` arround the mapbox container with `text-align: left;`

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I had the same problem even though I'm not using `vue-mapbox-gl`. (I'm just using mapbox-gl directly with Vue).

Comment: it's crazy the number of problems it solved for me, and a bit worrying as to how this is coded behind the scene. For me it solved the half-screen, but also the map box watermark style, the zoom not being centered on the mouse and the map not being movable... Anyway, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me, there is something dynamic with the `div` or the div is rendered later after the instantiation. I have not used vue, however.

I have had this problem with tabs and `div` rendered after the page load such as in tabs or triggered by JavaScript.

If you use `map.invalidateSize();` where `map` is the object instantiated. This will redraw the map. Try and put this after the window is loaded to test the code. Then perhaps it can be converted into the correct Vue implementation.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    map.invalidateSize();
});;
```

Comment: I only have a resize() method available on the object. invalidateSize() is not available and the resize() doesn't help.

Comment: Yes resize is the GL equiv. Try put a call back @map-load="mapLoaded" and call it that way - does that work?

Comment: Tried it this way, and it gets called but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Im stumpted then. If you can't work it out yourself, I would suggest posting it up as a Snippet to aid other SO users to help fix and test it.

Comment: Please check my own answer if you are interested. Thank you.